# From Kurfürstendamm to Europarc Dreilinden

Tags: public-transport, germany, berlin

I have to take a business trip to Berlin. My company offices are [here](http://europarc.de/en/), but I'll probably stay [in an hotel in Kurfürstendamm](http://www.nh-hotels.com/hotel/nh-berlin-kurfurstendamm?_ga=1.49868578.560078807.1426687915), just to be in a "center" location.

Can you guys suggest me a public transportation route from that address to the Europarc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the Kurfürstendamm or Ku'Damm is quite long. Depending on where you're staying the route might differ. But here are two examples:

If you're near the west end of Ku'Damm, take the *Ringbahn (S41)* from **S Halensee** to **S Westkreuz** and change for the *S7*.
Take the S7 (from **S+U Bhf Zoologischer Garten** if staying in that region) to **S Wannsee**.
From S Wannsee, take the *620 Bus* directly to Europarc.

This trip covers all three "zones" A, B, and C, so you might want to consider this when buying tickets.

If you consider taking a cab, the calculated price would be between 30 and 35 EUR. But since Europarc Dreilinden is in Brandenburg (not Berlin), prices are negotiable and might be higher.

Comment: Let me add that I'll probably stay in this hotel. http://www.nh-hotels.com/hotel/nh-berlin-kurfurstendamm?_ga=1.49868578.560078807.1426687915

Comment: @Napolux that hotel is in perfect walking distance to S Savignyplatz where you would once again grab the S7 to Wannsee.

Comment: http://fahrinfo.bvg.de/Fahrinfo/bin/query.bin/dn?from=10623%20Berlin-Charlottenburg,%20Grolmanstr.%2059!%26REQ0JourneyStopsSA1=2%26to=14532%20Kleinmachnow,%20Albert-Einstein-Ring%207!%26REQ0JourneyStopsZA1=2%26getstop=1%26